# Store two versions of a file at once using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm using Carrierwave and Fog gems to store a file to my Amazon S3 bucket (to `/files/file_id.txt`). I need to store a slightly different version of the file to a different location in the bucket (`/files/file_id_processed.txt`) at the same time (right after the original is stored). I don't want to create a separate uploader attribute for it on the model - is there any other way?

This my current method that stores the file:

```
def store_file(document)
  file_name = "tmp/#{document.id}.txt"

  File.open(file_name, 'w') do |f|
    document_content = document.content
    f.puts document_content
    document.raw_export.store!(f)
    document.save
  end

  # I need to store the document.processed_content

  File.delete(file_name) if File.exist?(file_name)
end
```

This is the Document model:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :raw_export, DocumentUploader
  # here I want to avoid adding something like:
  # mount_uploader :processed_export, DocumentUploader
end
```

This is my Uploader class:

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "files/"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(txt)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that you need similar file but with different name.
for this you need to create a version for file in uploader.

```
version :processed do
  process
end
```

and now second file name will be processed_{origional_file}.extension. if you want to change file name of second file you can use this link https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Customize-your-version-file-names

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track!
I'm posing my final solution below.

Answer (score 1):

This is how my final solution looks like (kinda) - based on Nitin Verma's answer:

I had to add a custom processor method for the version to the Uploader class:

```
# in document_uploader.rb

...

version :processed do
  process :do_the_replacements
end

def do_the_replacements
  original_content = @file.read
  File.open(current_path, 'w') do |f|
    f.puts original_content.gsub('Apples','Pears')
  end
end
```